# MySQL credentials are denied after rebooting

Tags: mysql, magento, reboot

I'm trying to install a copy of Magento with its mysql database in another computer.

To do that I copy the entire mysql folder. Everything is working as expected after recompile, change permissions and so on.

I can access the mysql database with the magento user with "mysql -u magento" and everything works fine.

When I reboot the server it throws a "Access dinied for user 'magento'@'localhost'. And I can not log in with mysql anymore.

If I recopy the whole /var/lib/mysql folder from my backup it will work again.

Why do my users/databases get removed after a server reboot?

Furthermore, all files from mysql that are not default in /var/lib/mysql are removed.

Comment: The best way that you should export and import the .sql file on your another localhost setup rather than copying MySQL folders.

Answer (score 0):

The right approach to move and SQL database from one server to another, is to create a backup of the database:

In the original server:
To export the database

```
mysqldump -uuser -p databasename > databasefile.sql
```

In the target server
To import: `mysql -uroot -p databasename < databasefile.sql`